# How to position a decorating text with effects on a curved path using 'left indent'?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, decorations

Using `text effects` nullifies the expected behavior from `text align = {left indent = {0.25\dimexpr\pgfdecoratedpathlength\relax}}` that should start typesetting the text at 25% of the path length away from its start, so how to make both work together?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[mark = none,
            decoration = {
                text = {My text},
                text align = { 
                    left indent = {0.25\dimexpr\pgfdecoratedpathlength\relax} 
                    },
                raise = -0.5ex,
                text effects along path,
                text effects/characters = {text along path, fill = white},
            },
            postaction = {decorate},
            ]
            {x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the package `pgfplots`: consider writing `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` or using another version into the preamble.

This answer does not solve the issue with `left indent` but uses a workaround by placing the text in a separate plot with `domain=-3.275:5`.
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[] {x^2};
    \addplot[
      domain=-3.275:5,
      decoration={
        text effects along path,
        text effects/characters={
          text along path,
          fill=white
        },
        text=My text,
        text align=left,
        raise=-0.5ex
      },
      decorate
    ]
    {x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```